# Using NAT in qemu

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have used Qemu to install a windows xp guest. The command I run is

```
qemu -m 2048 -gda winxp64.img \
    -boot d -usbdevice tablet \ 
    -enable-kvm -vnc :10 \
    -netdev user,id=network0 -device e1000,netdev=network0
```

However, inside the guest, I am not able to connect to the internet. Are the network configuration options correct?